# what is the cause of halo around dark objects (non-HDR)

Tags: post-processing, raw, sony, halos

This problem occurs often with scenes that have trees with the sky behind. I tend to raise the shadows and reduce the higligts (in RAW) to get a more pleasing image, I believe this is a normal thing to do.

Here is a [extreme] demo, original shot:
[image]

after raising the shadows (I raised more than usual to make the problem show more):
[image]

As you can see, dark has bright halo and bright has dark halo and I noticed that the darker the image the more apparent the effect. Here are my questions:

1. Is this a hardware or a software post processing artefact?
2. if it's hardware then do I have a faulty camera or is this normal?
3. is this the same problem that occurs with HDR shots?

and of course, can it be fixed?

The image was taken with a Sony a6300, 10-18mm lens

EDIT:

1. software used: tried both Luminar 2018 and Darktable
2. the attached images are just screenshots directly form the editing software

Comment: For completeness: what software do you use to process the RAW file? The actual adjustments done in the image might differ per software package.

Comment: It's possible to ameliorate it a bit - see https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCViq.jpg - but I'm wondering if the Sony has some kind of internal contrast modifier like Nikon's Active D-Lighting… see this Q & A -  https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/93500/what-causes-this-dark-halo-around-the-sun

Comment: @Tetsujin how did you ameliorate it? is it a feature or you did it manually?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke see update question, I used Luminar and darktable. I don't have access to LR to test this but I could upload the .ARW for someone to test if needed

Comment: That was just using the front page of Adobe PhotoRAW [white/black/high/low & a little clarity] with a bit of de-noising, as the image was so small. 2 mins work. You could do a lot better on the full-size original.

Comment: To clarify: You're using a "shadows" slider to brighten the image? If so, the halo is likely related to how the algorithm isolates the shadows.

Comment: [It's all HDR (High Dynamic Range Imaging) when you are squeezing a wide DR scene into a display medium with less DR than the scene contains.](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/80598/15871)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a processing/software artifact and the same as what is encountered when tone mapping HDR images... that's basically what you are doing; re-mapping the tones, only w/in a single image.

Also check other contrast type settings; sharpening, clarity, etc. Those types of settings try to preserve/increase the perception of details by adding localized contrast; i.e. light next to dark/dark next to light.

Comment: so this is the result of local contrast? seems like the software I'm using is adding clarity internally when I increase the shadows and reduce the highlights

Answer (score 0):

Confirming @Steven Kersting's [answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/114142/84799), the problem **is** a software issue caused by some internal tone mapping/local contrast, the "shadows" slider shouldn't normally cause the hallo but in this case it is.

I managed to fix the halo problem using [RawTherapee](https://rawtherapee.com/), by sliding the shadows slider I got the results I was expecting (without the halo). This indicates different implementation of the feature, which in my opinion is more accurate:

[image: screenshot from RawTherapee's recovered shadows]