# Is there a way to get rid of this glowing effect?

Tags: night, night-photography, capture-one, affinity-photo, luminosity

I'm trying to figure out how to get rid of the glow around the tree in the bottom right.

I've gotten as far as thinking it's some form of luminosity due to reflections at ground level (this is in my backyard in an urban area), but I can't seem to find any specific information on how to get rid of it, other than that it is probably possible...

I'd like it to blend in nicer with the actual night sky, so in my mind, that's finding a way to reduce its brightness/contrast/exposure/something with a very accurate mask?

I'm using Capture One Pro 11, and do have Affinity Photo available to me.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: What camera? It looks like HDR, but it could possible be a setting similar to Active-D in Nikons - see this for how I discovered it -https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/93500/what-causes-this-dark-halo-around-the-sun It is removable after the fact if that's what it is.

Comment: Does Capture One Pro have an equivalent to the "Clarity" slider in Lightroom? It's a local contrast enhancer that gives the same affect as "detail enhancement" in many HDR applications.

Comment: It's a sony alpha a7iii, taken in RAW. I've got all their post processing stuff turned off.

Comment: @michaelC your comment about clairty made me go back and take a look at capture one pro... And then take a look at the source picture. And then realised that it was actually the clarity slider that had enhanced the light around the trees that much... I'm gonna try to rejig it and see if I can get better! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really looks like the effect of post-processing. So, you get rid of it by not processing that way in the first place. You may have presets applied in your software which makes it seem like you haven't done processing!

- Open the original file with a simple image viewer to confirm that the glow is *not* there.
- If it is not, then try to reimport with all processing disabled.
- If is *is* in the original, then you will need some manual work to clean that up. Something like a neutral effect applies with a mask or brush. Looking at the shape is so following the tree so closely, it is unlikely to be in the scene. If there was a lamp-post behind the tree, I would expect a rounder glow but who knows what's behind?!

Comment: Ya, MichaelC's comment actually made me go do that already, and as you said, it was actually the clarity slider that had really bumped that up. I've done a bit of masking now to prevent that portion of it from being affected, and it looks heaps better! Thank you!